# Configurar Heroku com proxy

Tags: heroku, proxy

Estou tentando começar a usar o Heroku para testar um app java web que fiz, baixei o Toolbelt do Heroku porém na hora de logar ele lança um *Unable to connect to Heroku API, please check internet connectivity and try again.*

Aqui onde trabalho é utilizado um proxy e como é dito no site do Heroku:

Note that if you’re behind a firewall that requires use of a proxy to connect with external HTTP/HTTPS services, you can set the HTTP_PROXY or HTTPS_PROXY environment variables before running the heroku command.

Tentei adicionar o proxy nas variáveis de ambiente mas continuo recebendo o mesmo erro. Alguém já passou por isso?

Answer (score 2):

Muito como no caso [desta pergunta em inglês neste link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9648559/how-to-push-to-heroku-behind-a-proxy), é possível que o proxy através do qual tentas conectar-se esteja bloqueando a porta TCP 22, usada para SSH nos sistemas Unix.
Como tal porta não é comumente utilizada por aplicações de usuários leigos, mesmo nos sistemas windows, firewalls típicos em workspaces são configurados para impedir conexões através da mesma.